# Loading a javascript file within a javascript file

Tags: javascript, file, loading

If I want to load another javascript file from a javascript file (ex. when I complete a level in a game), how would I do this?

(I'll add what I've tried in a minute)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
var getScript = function(filePath, loadedCallback) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        jsFileScriptTag = document.createElement('script');

    jsFileScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jsFileScriptTag.src = filePath;
    jsFileScriptTag.onreadystatechange = loadedCallback;
    jsFileScriptTag.onload = loadedCallback;
    head.appendChild(jsFileScriptTag);
};

//ussage
getScript('/js/myFile.js', function() {
    //do something when the script has loaded.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I came across another way, which is to use web workers. Have you ever tried that method out?